# Как при клике на кнопку изменить ее спрайт?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть кнопка button1 и игрок должен кликать по ней 
При клике должен Image кнопки меняться

Например:
В играх есть кнопка вкл/выкл звук,при нажатии которой меняется ее Image

Comment: Может сделать массив спрайтов и паблик метод, меняющий спрайт по индексу массива, который срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку. Или метод в котором принимает в спрайт рендерер спрайт с ресурсов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Sprite;
```

Где **button** - Ваша кнопка, а **Sprite** - спрайт.